# List permissions

Tags: 2010, permissions, security

I want to disallow a specific list only to be only read only for all users in the site.
The only one with permissions would be the site collection administrator of course.

I stoped inheriting permissions for this list, and put read access.

The question is, Is there more than one way to do this? Or is this the easiest one OOTB?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the proper way to do it OOTB.